# How should IPC be handled in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In a past .NET Framework project, our main application ran as a Windows Service and we used WCF NetNamedPipeBinding to communicate with a WPF front end application.  Since WCF won't be a part of .NET Core, how should I handle inter-process communication?  The new application (worker service) needs to handle typical RPC and also push data to another process.

I'm considering the following:

1. Named pipes.  This would work, but these are effectively streams in the API.  Handling the streams and establishing a protocol seems like a pain.
2. gRPC, but that would involve converting a number of data models to protobuf which isn't desirable.
3. SignalR, but that would involve hosting an ASP.NET Core application inside my service.  Seems like an overkill.

Any insight or alternatives would be appreciated!

Comment: On #2 - note that protobuf-net has gRPC hooks, which means you can use gRPC with many normal existing POCO models - you don't need to refactor them completely. However, now I'm wondering whether I should write something to simplify local IPC via #1...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Marc.  I've been using Google.Protobuf and Grpc/Grpc.Tools, but maybe I should take a closer look at your protobuf-net library.  gRPC over named pipes would be awesome!

Comment: [here's the "getting started" page](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted). Doing full gRPC over named pipes? I'd need to think; a lot of pieces assume HTTP3, but I guess it may be possible to spoof those bits... But tbh I was thinking more of a simple message queue perhaps with RPC activation built in.

Comment: WCF server support might not be Microsoft's goal for .NET Core, but your option list missed the community effort, https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF

Answer (score 23):

Four recent *low-effort* options that I would consider:

### MessagePipe (new)

> "[MessagePipe](https://github.com/Cysharp/MessagePipe) is a high-performance in-memory/distributed
> messaging pipeline for .NET and Unity. It supports all cases of
> Pub/Sub usage, mediator pattern for CQRS, EventAggregator of
> Prism(V-VM decoupling), IPC(Interprocess Communication)-RPC, etc.
>
> ```
> - Dependency-injection first
> - Filter pipeline
> - better event
> - sync/async
> - keyed/keyless
> - buffered/bufferless
> - singleton/scoped
> - broadcast/response(+many)
> - in-memory/interprocess/distributed
> ```
>
> MessagePipe is faster than standard C# event and 78 times faster than
> Prism's EventAggregator."

Haven't tried, but this author is a .NET legend.

### gRPC

For larger projects you can use [Visual ReCode](https://visualrecode.com/features/wcf_to_grpc/) to automate the conversion of your projects from WCF to gRPC. I have limited experience with this project, but looks very promising and gRPC is definitely the future...

### ServiceWire

[ServiceWire](https://github.com/tylerjensen/ServiceWire) is a deliciously lightweight IPC/RPC library. Cross-platform, supports TCP/IP & named pipe channels. Insanely fast and easy to use- simply add [Serializable] to all classes that need to be sent over the wire. I really love this framework.

Only downsides are:

- no SSL support, but does own encryption and automatic compression
- no .NET Core standard DI support, but it's server implementation makes this a non-issue

### cloudtoid Interprocess (pub/sub, not RPC)

> [Cloudtoid Interprocess](https://github.com/cloudtoid/interprocess) is a cross-platform shared memory queue for fast communication between processes (Interprocess Communication or IPC). It uses a shared memory-mapped file for extremely fast and efficient communication between processes and it is used internally by Microsoft.

Mixing this with [CySharp MemoryPack](https://github.com/Cysharp/MemoryPack) for serialisation makes for very fast IPC, but requires a bit of manual serialisation/de-serialisation.